# Combining Page Manager Search with Drupal core search

Tags: panels, search, chaos-tool-suite

I'm in need of a search solution for panels, and [Page Manager Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_search) seems to be the only one out there that doesn't involve [Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr). The problem I'm having with integrating it into my site is that it's results for panels content is set up to be separate from Drupal core search. What I really need is something that combines the two. Anyone have any luck getting Page Manager Search results to flow seamlessly into standard Drupal core search results?

I'm also curious why this module shows so little active usage (178 sites at the time of this post), when the problem of indexing panels content hasn't been otherwise solved outside of Solr. Is it just that everyone is using Solr?

Comment: I'd imagine it has low usage as Panels is mainly used to display nodes / taxonomy terms / users etc. which are already searchable. Are you sure you want to create lots of custom pages instead of nodes where you would display each field as a pane? As a CMS, it's kind of how it's meant to be used.

Comment: @NiallMurphy On our site, we have quite a bit of content added through Fieldable Panels Panes, and additional custom panes. Also, even if we were displaying the content you listed, wouldn't we still have the issue of search linking to the node, etc. pages rather than the page manager page? Or is it set up to link to the "host" (i.e. page manager) page?

Comment: It would link to the panel page which overrides the node/%nid. But if you really need to have a lot of custom content etc., maybe you don't have a choice. Check the Panelizer module though which lets you have a different panel per node page meaning you still have lots of customization but each page is a node and your reusable fields would be automatically searchable. I'm sorry that this is off-topic but site building advice can be as valuable as specific help sometimes before you go too far down a road that ends up being limited.

Comment: No problem, this is still helpful. So is it the case that only reusable fields are searchable?

Comment: Yeah I believe so. Could you give an example of what you use fieldable panel panes for? You could just add all of the fields you could possibly need to a content type and build one panel that would display them.

Comment: FPP are in use for a bunch of different custom panes to allow for a really modular layout. Our sub-theme is based on Kalatheme, which is heavy on panels and panels layouts, and allows for pieces of content to be moved anywhere on a page. I can't think of how a content type would allow for this flexibility.

Comment: Pabelizer would give the flexibility while using the node system would automatically create the bulk of the panel from a node form. Then your fieldable panel panes for very custom content can be added after. Anyways, I'm sorry I can't help with your original question. I'll delete these comments tomorrow to reduce clutter.